# I need to update a Blazor page to update whenever the query string changes

Tags: c#, blazor, radzen

I have a Blazor component named NavBar.razor that displays a Radzen navigation menu with a list of tags. When the user clicks a tag (RadzenPanelMenuItem), the component OrderBrowser.razor is loaded into the page next to the menu. The query string lets OrderBrowser.razor know what tag was selected. (See the OnInitializedAsync method below.) The component loads the associated orders into a grid.

This works fine the first time the user clicks a tag, but when they click a different tag, the OnInitializedAsync method does not execute, even though the uri changes. So I added an event handler to force a reload when the uri changes. This works, but, for some reason, it seems to reload twice, resulting in an undesirable blink when it reloads the 2nd time.

Does anyone know a better way to do this? Thanks.

Code from NavBar.razor:

```
@foreach (var item in TagsAndCounts)
{
    <Radzen.Blazor.RadzenPanelMenuItem 
        Text="@(item.Tag + " (" + item.Count + ")")"
        Path="@("orders/browse?tag=" + item.Tag)" />
}
```

Order grid from OrderBrowser.razor:

```
<OrderGrid Data="@orders" AllowPaging="false" />
```

Code from OrderBrowser.razor:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();

    NavManager.LocationChanged += NavManager_LocationChanged;

    var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);

    if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("tag", out var tag))
    {
        orders = await orderService.GetOrdersForTagAsync(tag);
    }
}

private void NavManager_LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NavManager.NavigateTo(NavManager.Uri, forceLoad: true);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a requirement to use a query string for "tag"?  If not, then you could use a URL Path of `orders/browse/{tag}` and then OnInitializeAsync() will be called.

Comment: At first I thought this was going to work, but it looks like OnInitializeAsync() is only called if the orders/browse part of the URL changes. It ignores changes to {tag}, just like ignores changes to the query string.

Comment: Are you creating the Route parameter correctly?  Here is a resource for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-parameters

Comment: I  believe so. Here's my route: @page "/orders/browse/{tag}"

Comment: Cool.  You have that @page at the top of `OrderBrowser.razor`, that's good.  Do you have a `tag` C# property defined to accept the tag value?  If yes, then you also need to change the URL `Path = "@("orders/browse/{item.Tag}"` that you point to from your NavBar.razor component.

Comment: I used Path="@("orders/browse/" + tag.Tag)". That works to change the URL -- the new URL is displayed in the address bar -- but the page still doesn't automatically update. It seems to ignore changes to {tag} the same way it ignores changes to query strings.

Answer (score 6):

Use this event

```
[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery]
public string? Page { get; set; } = "0";

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
     //Fire your Code her
    }
```

Comment: Wow.  Why didn't I know about `SupplyParameterFromQuery`?

Answer (score 2):

When you go from: `yourUrl/tag/tagname1` and click to link `yourUrl/tag/tagname2` it does not fire `OnInitializedAsync`, because new page was not created. It is intended and correct behavior. But bit confusing.

You can leverage new, with .net6 introduced, capability of `SupplyFromQueryParameter` attribute, which will change its value based on query string.

```
 [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "tag")] public string Tag { get; set; } = "";
```

Now you can do the magic inside seeter of the `Tag` property. Or, if you need to call async method inside setter (which is not a good practice), you can use `OnParametersSet` method. It is called right after parameters has been changed. So you also need a mechanism to check if tag parameter has been changed (because it is called every time *some* parameter has been changed )

```cs
bool tagUpdated = true;
string _tag ="";
[Parameter,SupplyParameterFromQuery] public string Tag { get => _tag; set { if (value != _tag) { _tag = value; tagUpdated = true; } } } 

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
if (tagUpdated)
    {
    tagUpdated = false;
    await YourAsyncCallAndOtherMagic();
    }
}
```

Note, that `SupplyFromQueryParameter` works only on pages (`.razor` components with `@page` directive)

(still not the most beautiful solution I guess. Open for suggestions...)

Comment: Didn't this require a routing context? I tried something similar a month ago, but sadly I had to give up because this wouldn't work on the AppComponent without hacky workarounds. In angular you can simply subscribe to a specific query parameter, from anywhere, and act accordingly.

Comment: My company hasn't gone to .net6 yet, but I'll make a note of this for when we do. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. It's still a bit of a hack, but it seems to work. If anybody has any better solutions, please let me know. I just changed the event handler to get the new URL and update the page, instead of forcing a reload.

```
private async void NavManager_LocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    orders = await orderService.GetOrdersForTagAsync(tag);
    var index = NavManager.Uri.LastIndexOf("/");
    tag = NavManager.Uri.Substring(index + 1);
    if (tag != "open_orders")
    {
       StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```